# SQL Query with Group , Order by and Random at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, random, group-by

I was unable to find anything similar to this problem.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Orden` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;


INSERT INTO `test` (`Id`, `Nombre`, `Orden`) VALUES
    (1, 'Mark', NULL),
    (2, 'David', 1),
    (3, 'John', 1),
    (4, 'David', 2),
    (5, 'John', 3),
    (6, 'John', 2),
    (7, 'William', NULL);
```

As we see John and David has more than one row and there's a Order column so we can order it simply using ORDER BY Name ASC, Order ASC but this is not exactly what i need..

[image]

Here is the problem: i would like to know if its possible to order by name and make some kind of group for each name, then by order by its Order, and then apply a final ORDER BY RAND() so you still viewing all the rows from david, mark, john and William, but in random order..

[image]

So every time you run the query, the order is completely random but still with some order..

[image]

Here is a Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/038bd7/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
select Nombre, rand() rnd 
from test 
group by Nombre
```

returns a random number for each unique name in the table.
Join it to the table and sort first by that random number and then by `Orden`:

```
select t.* 
from test t 
inner join (select Nombre, rand() rnd from test group by Nombre) r
on r.Nombre = t.Nombre
order by r.rnd, t.Orden
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=742c6800fc9286652c0244fb5b20c3fa).
Results:

```
> Id | Nombre  | Orden
> -: | :------ | ----:
>  7 | William |  null
>  1 | Mark    |  null
>  2 | David   |     1
>  4 | David   |     2
>  3 | John    |     1
>  6 | John    |     2
>  5 | John    |     3

> Id | Nombre  | Orden
> -: | :------ | ----:
>  2 | David   |     1
>  4 | David   |     2
>  3 | John    |     1
>  6 | John    |     2
>  5 | John    |     3
>  1 | Mark    |  null
>  7 | William |  null

> Id | Nombre  | Orden
> -: | :------ | ----:
>  2 | David   |     1
>  4 | David   |     2
>  1 | Mark    |  null
>  7 | William |  null
>  3 | John    |     1
>  6 | John    |     2
>  5 | John    |     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I really thought this would work, but it seems not to. I'm posting it anyway, in case it inspires others...

```
select * from test 
  order by field(nombre,
  (select group_concat(distinct concat('\'',nombre,'\'') order by rand()) from test)
  );
```

This seems to work...

```
select @i:= group_concat(distinct nombre order by rand()) from test;

select *,find_in_set(nombre,@i) n from test order by n,orden
```